# How can I store documentation in a pickle file?

Tags: python, pickle

In Python, I generate quite often a pickle file to conserve the work I have done during programming.

Is there any possibility to store something like a docstring in the pickle that explains how this pickle was generated and what it's meaning is.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly are you pickling? Show some code so that your question is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Mostly they are pandas DataFrames, but sometimes also lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can combine all kinds of items into dictionaries, tuples, and lists before pickling them, I would say the most straightforward solution would be to use a dictionary that has a docstring key.

```
pickle_dict = {'objs': [some, stuff, inhere],
               'docstring': 'explanation of those objects'}
```

Of course, depending on what you are pickling, you may want key-value pairs for each object instead of a list of objects.

When you open the pickle back up, you can just read the docstring to remember how this pickle came to be.

---

As an alternative solution, I often just need to save one or two integer values about the pickle. In this case, I choose to save in the title of the pickle file. Depending on what you are doing, this could be preferred so you can read the "docstring" without having to unpickle it.

Answer (score 1):

DataFrames and lists don't typically have docstrings because they are data. The docstring specification says:

> A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a *module, function, class, or method definition.* Such a docstring becomes the `__doc__` special attribute of that object.

You can create any of these to make a docstring associated with the process that **uses** your data. The main `class` of your module for example.

```
class MyClass:
    """My docstring"""

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df # Your dataframe
    ...
```

Something like this seems like it is closest to what you were asking within the conventions of the language.